# how to take a line from a text to use as input for a function python

Tags: python, input, iteration, shapely

Hi guys I have a text fill with some geodata that looks like this:

[(-76.34666,40.006886),(-76.34666,40.073017),(-76.25411,40.073017),(76.25411,40.006886)]
[(-84.82031,38.403187)),(-84.82031,42.327133),(-80.51862,42.327133),(-80.51862,38.403187)]

now i want to take it line by line as an input for a polygon function. I first tried to make it with one line befor i try iteration but it wont work. That is my code for now:

```
    from shapely.wkt import loads as load_wkt
    from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon

    f = open('koordinat.txt', 'r')
    line = f.readline()
    p = Polygon(line)
    print (p.centroid)
```

I get all the time the same error by the "p = Polygon(line)" and
"A LinearRing must have at least 3 coordinate tuples" but when take one of the lines and put it in the function manual it works fine.

Any help? Also an example for a possible iteration would be nice :)

Comment: `line` is still a string. Convert it into a list of tuples, and maybe that'll work?

Comment: When you read the line from the file, you get a string. You need to convert the string to a list of coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing a string to `Polygon`, but it's expecting a list of coordinates (numbers).

Try this:

```
import ast
line = ast.literal_eval(f.readline())
```